# Funding for Phd positions in Australia

Tags: phd, funding, australia

Are PhD positions in Australia fully funded for international students like in the US and Europe? I shall be applying for PhD programs in Astronomy and Astrophysics. Also, are scholarships given for masters program in the same field?

Comment: I am assuming you are an international students.  Each year, every university has N number of scholarships that it  offers to international students.  These are highly competitive.  Some academic staff may have grants that have some scholarships. These scholarships are given out by the owner of the grants.  Also, government research arm such as CSIRO may have some scholarships, and given out in partnership with a university.  Usually, universities prefer to award scholarships to PhD students.